# Debugging a Windows CE application which uses a Microsoft Azure service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, wcf, windows-ce, visual-studio-2008-sp1

This question has probably less to do with actual programming and more to do with environment setup.

I'm developing an application for a Windows CE device, which will use a service hosted in Microsoft Azure. Obviously, this is all under development, and the service itself has not yet been uploaded to Azure. So I'm using the emulators provided by MS to deploy the service locally. Also, I don't think uploading the service to Azure just to debug it is a good idea, as that could net us a bill for Azure we don't yet want to pay.

Also, please note, I'm using VS2008 for the Windows CE project and VS2010 for the Azure project (thank you MS for dropping support for mobile devices -_-).

The problem is, the service seems to be accessible only via 127.0.0.1 or localhost, and if I physically connect a Windows CE device or use an emulated one, it becomes a new entity on the network, and cannot access that service any more.

How can I debug my Window CE application and have it see the service, whilst still being able to debug the service itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know if this was intentional, or if I found one of the mentioned hacks, but I saw that IIS hosts the Azure site I created on port 5100, and the binding for this site is `*`, so it accepts all connections.

Using this I could access the service from my emulator, and I could still debug all Azure related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the development fabric (the compute emulator that allows you to build an azure application and debug it locally) is only meant for local development. There are some hacks that allow you to get around that, but I wouldn't recommend it.

My recommendation would be to spin up the service in a more traditional hosting environment, at least in these early stages. You can define it as a web app just as you always would have, and get it functioning. Then, when you know its mostly complete, create a cloud service project and do an add existing to bring your web app into the cloud service solution. Once in, its a simple matter to add the web app as a web role.

From there, you can complete testing of the service in both the local and hosted azure environments as needed. This allows you to minimize your development costs while still leveraging the power of the cloud. As an upside, you also have done most of the basic work to ensure your service is compatible with multiple deployment scenarios giving you a greater degree of choice for its final production state.

Comment: This would work, assuming the service didn't use, for example, Azure Storage. Considering my proficiency in Azure Table Storage (that is, I'm still new at this and stuff tends to surprise me), I need to test that as well.

Comment: You can deploy locally and still access hosted items like storage. Again, if you're loosely coupled, this allows you to develop portions on premisees and link to hosted or on-premises resources as necessary. So use dev storage locally during early phases of service development, then eventually move it up hosted storage while the service matures. Unless you have a battery of developers hammering on it, Azure Storage charges should be minimal (especially compared to the time developers could spend getting individual environments setup).